# How do i find where the button is clicked so that I can position something over there?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, popup, toast

I want the popup or modal or toast to appear right where the button in clicked in react.
But I was unable to find anything on this. Anything I could find was something like,it appeared in the center or the top or something predefined I guess still not right where the the button was clicked.
How should approach this?

Comment: Are you looking for something like a [tooltip](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/tooltips/)?

Answer (score 0):

https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events

The MouseEvent parameter on the onClick callback contains the x and y coordinates of the click.

```
const handleClick = (mouseEvent) => {
    console.log(`x = ${mouseEvent.clientX}, y = ${mouseEvent.clientY}`)
}
```

React provides 3 different coordinates client, page, and screen the example above makes use of the client coordinates. You can read more about their differences in the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent)

Answer (score 0):

```
const box = document.querySelector('#box');

box.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(`Horizontal: ${clientX}, Vertical: ${clientY}`);
    // Take Position Current onClick
});
```

You can set top by clientY, left by clientX from event listener